# Add text to unlocked screen on iPhone

Tags: iphone

How I can add some text to unlocked screen on iPhone? I saw some application, that write text on unlocked screen.

Comment: Do you mean the Springboard (the application launcher), or to the lock screen? Apps shouldn't be able to write to the Springboard (unless the device is jailbroken). The only way I'm aware of to "write" to the lock screen is via a notification (assuming the app is set to have its notifications shown on the lock screen).

Comment: Were you looking at an application for a jailbroken iPhone? The only way I've seen text added to the screen is by adding text to the background image.

Comment: Here: [link](http://www.simonblog.com/2009/01/21/lock-calendar-display-calendar-event-iphone-lock-screen/) but that application is old and it's not from appstore

Comment: broad topic to discuss in here. Be specific on your question.

Answer (score 0):

You need jailbreakers iPhone and use application "Custom Lock" from http://rpetri.ch/repo/
This may not be in the AppStore, because it violates the rules of Apple's applications that may be in the AppStore. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cRFt_ttEwpA&feature=player_embedded